# Use Ajax return value in Jade file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am using ExpressJS together with the Jade template engine. I am trying to do the following:

In a Jade file, I extract a variable which I need in a JavaScript file. In this JavaScript file, I send an Ajax request to the Express server. This returns some data and I would like to put this data in another variable which I can use again in my Jade file.

Here is my code:

**Jade file:**

```
script.
    var userID = '#{userObject.ID}'; //Extract variable
script(src='/javascripts/account.js') //needed in this file

p
    | #{papersObject} //This should be the result from the Ajax request
```

**Ajax request:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/accountdata',
        /* jshint ignore:start */
        data: {'personId': userID},
        /* jshint ignore:end */
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            var papersObject = JSON.stringify(data.result);
        }
    });

});
```

**app.js:**

```
var accountData = require('./routes/accountdata');
app.use('/accountdata', accountData);
```

**Route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    data = //Some database function
    res.send({result: data});
});
module.exports = router;
```

Why is `#{papersObject}` not showing on my page? How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server side code and client side code run on different computers. The Jade template is processed before the Ajax request is even sent.

If you want to add the data to the page, then you need to use DOM manipulation to do so.

e.g. [with `append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: How can I use DOM manipulation to add `<li>` elements to an `<ul>`

Comment: Or rendering the data in JADE template from express server side and return the HTML as ajax response, and append the HTML to DOM container from ajax success call.